# Unable de create a Liferay 7 - JSF based plugin

Tags: eclipse, liferay, ivy

I am working with **Luna** latest version, **Liferay IDE 3.x**, **Liferay 7**.

Some weeks ago all worked fine(MVC portlet), but now it does not.

I searched on google but in vain (so few documentation).

I changed ivy URL and switched off my firewall but in vain.

```
[Console output redirected to file:E:\WORK\LIFERAY\TRAININGS\.metadata\.plugins\com.liferay.ide.sdk.core\sdk.log]
Buildfile: E:\WORK\LIFERAY\TRAININGS\com.liferay.portal.plugins.sdk-7.0\portlets\build.xml
    [mkdir] Created dir: E:\WORK\LIFERAY\TRAININGS\com.liferay.portal.plugins.sdk-7.0\.ivy
     [copy] Copying 1 file to E:\WORK\LIFERAY\TRAININGS\com.liferay.portal.plugins.sdk-7.0\.ivy
[ivy:resolve] :: Apache Ivy 2.4.0 - 20141213170938 :: http://ant.apache.org/ivy/ ::
[ivy:resolve] :: loading settings :: file = E:\WORK\LIFERAY\TRAININGS\com.liferay.portal.plugins.sdk-7.0\ivy-settings.xml
[ivy:resolve] :: problems summary ::
[ivy:resolve] :::: WARNINGS
[ivy:resolve]       ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[ivy:resolve]       ::          UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         ::
[ivy:resolve]       ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[ivy:resolve]       :: javax.activation#activation;1.1: several problems occurred while resolving dependency: javax.activation#activation;1.1 {default=[default]}:
[ivy:resolve]   liferay-private: unable to get resource for javax/activation#activation;1.1: res=/javax/activation/activation/1.1/activation-1.1-javadoc.jar: java.net.MalformedURLException: no protocol: /javax/activation/activation/1.1/activation-1.1-javadoc.jar
[ivy:resolve]   liferay-private: unable to get resource for javax/activation#activation;1.1: res=/javax/activation/activation/1.1/activation-1.1.pom: java.net.MalformedURLException: no protocol: /javax/activation/activation/1.1/activation-1.1.pom
[ivy:resolve]       :: org.apache.ant#ant-apache-bsf;1.8.3: several problems occurred while resolving dependency: org.apache.ant#ant-apache-bsf;1.8.3 {default=[default]}:
[ivy:resolve]   several problems occurred while resolving dependency: org.apache.ant#ant-parent;1.8.3 {}:
[ivy:resolve]   liferay-private: unable to get resource for org/apache/ant#ant-parent;1.8.3: res=/org/apache/ant/ant-parent/1.8.3/ant-parent-1.8.3.jar: java.net.MalformedURLException: no protocol: /org/apache/ant/ant-parent/1.8.3/ant-parent-1.8.3.jar
[ivy:resolve]   liferay-private: unable to get resource for org/apache/ant#ant-parent;1.8.3: res=/org/apache/ant/ant-parent/1.8.3/ant-parent-1.8.3.pom: java.net.MalformedURLException: no protocol: /org/apache/ant/ant-parent/1.8.3/ant-parent-1.8.3.pom
[ivy:resolve]   liferay-private: unable to get resource for org/apache/ant#ant-apache-bsf;1.8.3: res=/org/apache/ant/ant-apache-bsf/1.8.3/ant-apache-bsf-1.8.3.pom: java.net.MalformedURLException: no protocol: /org/apache/ant/ant-apache-bsf/1.8.3/ant-apache-bsf-1.8.3.pom
[ivy:resolve]       :: org.tigris.antelope#antelopetasks;3.2.10: several problems occurred while resolving dependency: org.tigris.antelope#antelopetasks;3.2.10 {default=[default]}:
[ivy:resolve]   liferay-private: unable to get resource for org/tigris/antelope#antelopetasks;3.2.10: res=/org/tigris/antelope/antelopetasks/3.2.10/antelopetasks-3.2.10-sources.jar: java.net.MalformedURLException: no protocol: /org/tigris/antelope/antelopetasks/3.2.10/antelopetasks-3.2.10-sources.jar
[ivy:resolve]   liferay-private: unable to get resource for org/tigris/antelope#antelopetasks;3.2.10: res=/org/tigris/antelope/antelopetasks/3.2.10/antelopetasks-3.2.10.pom: java.net.MalformedURLException: no protocol: /org/tigris/antelope/antelopetasks/3.2.10/antelopetasks-3.2.10.pom
[ivy:resolve]       :: org.beanshell#bsh;2.0b4: several problems occurred while resolving dependency: org.beanshell#bsh;2.0b4 {default=[default]}:
[ivy:resolve]   several problems occurred while resolving dependency: org.beanshell#beanshell;2.0b4 {}:
[ivy:resolve]   liferay-private: unable to get resource for org/beanshell#beanshell;2.0b4: res=/org/beanshell/beanshell/2.0b4/beanshell-2.0b4.jar: java.net.MalformedURLException: no protocol: /org/beanshell/beanshell/2.0b4/beanshell-2.0b4.jar
[ivy:resolve]   liferay-private: unable to get resource for org/beanshell#beanshell;2.0b4: res=/org/beanshell/beanshell/2.0b4/beanshell-2.0b4.pom: java.net.MalformedURLException: no protocol: /org/beanshell/beanshell/2.0b4/beanshell-2.0b4.pom
[ivy:resolve]   liferay-private: unable to get resource for org/beanshell#bsh;2.0b4: res=/org/beanshell/bsh/2.0b4/bsh-2.0b4.pom: java.net.MalformedURLException: no protocol: /org/beanshell/bsh/2.0b4/bsh-2.0b4.pom
[ivy:resolve]       :: bsf#bsf;2.4.0: several problems occurred while resolving dependency: bsf#bsf;2.4.0 {default=[default]}:
[ivy:resolve]   several problems occurred while resolving dependency: org.apache#apache;3 {}:
[ivy:resolve]   liferay-private: unable to get resource for org/apache#apache;3: res=/org/apache/apache/3/apache-3.jar: java.net.MalformedURLException: no protocol: /org/apache/apache/3/apache-3.jar
[ivy:resolve]   liferay-private: unable to get resource for org/apache#apache;3: res=/org/apache/apache/3/apache-3.pom: java.net.MalformedURLException: no protocol: /org/apache/apache/3/apache-3.pom
[ivy:resolve]   liferay-private: unable to get resource for bsf#bsf;2.4.0: res=/bsf/bsf/2.4.0/bsf-2.4.0.pom: java.net.MalformedURLException: no protocol: /bsf/bsf/2.4.0/bsf-2.4.0.pom
[ivy:resolve]       :: javax.ccpp#ccpp;1.0: several problems occurred while resolving dependency: javax.ccpp#ccpp;1.0 {default=[default]}:
[ivy:resolve]   liferay-private: unable to get resource for javax/ccpp#ccpp;1.0: res=/javax/ccpp/ccpp/1.0/ccpp-1.0-sources.jar: java.net.MalformedURLException: no protocol: /javax/ccpp/ccpp/1.0/ccpp-1.0-sources.jar
[ivy:resolve]   liferay-private: unable to get resource for javax/ccpp#ccpp;1.0: res=/javax/ccpp/ccpp/1.0/ccpp-1.0.pom: java.net.MalformedURLException: no protocol: /javax/ccpp/ccpp/1.0/ccpp-1.0.pom
[ivy:resolve]       :: commons-logging#commons-logging;1.1.1: several problems occurred while resolving dependency: commons-logging#commons-logging;1.1.1 {default=[default]}:
[ivy:resolve]   several problems occurred while resolving dependency: org.apache.commons#commons-parent;5 {}:
[ivy:resolve]   several problems occurred while resolving dependency: org.apache#apache;4 {}:
[ivy:resolve]   liferay-private: unable to get resource for org/apache#apache;4: res=/org/apache/apache/4/apache-4.jar: java.net.MalformedURLException: no protocol: /org/apache/apache/4/apache-4.jar
[ivy:resolve]   liferay-private: unable to get resource for org/apache#apache;4: res=/org/apache/apache/4/apache-4.pom: java.net.MalformedURLException: no protocol: /org/apache/apache/4/apache-4.pom
[ivy:resolve]   liferay-private: unable to get resource for org/apache/commons#commons-parent;5: res=/org/apache/commons/commons-parent/5/commons-parent-5.pom: java.net.MalformedURLException: no protocol: /org/apache/commons/commons-parent/5/commons-parent-5.pom
[ivy:resolve]   liferay-private: unable to get resource for commons-logging#commons-logging;1.1.1: res=/commons-logging/commons-logging/1.1.1/commons-logging-1.1.1.pom: java.net.MalformedURLException: no protocol: /commons-logging/commons-logging/1.1.1/commons-logging-1.1.1.pom
[ivy:resolve]       :: com.google.errorprone#error_prone_ant;1.0.8: several problems occurred while resolving dependency: com.google.errorprone#error_prone_ant;1.0.8 {default=[default]}:
[ivy:resolve]   several problems occurred while resolving dependency: com.google.errorprone#error_prone_parent;1.0.8 {}:
[ivy:resolve]   several problems occurred while resolving dependency: com.google#google;5 {}:
[ivy:resolve]   liferay-private: unable to get resource for com/google#google;5: res=/com/google/google/5/google-5.jar: java.net.MalformedURLException: no protocol: /com/google/google/5/google-5.jar
[ivy:resolve]   liferay-private: unable to get resource for com/google#google;5: res=/com/google/google/5/google-5.pom: java.net.MalformedURLException: no protocol: /com/google/google/5/google-5.pom
[ivy:resolve]   liferay-private: unable to get resource for com/google/errorprone#error_prone_parent;1.0.8: res=/com/google/errorprone/error_prone_parent/1.0.8/error_prone_parent-1.0.8.pom: java.net.MalformedURLException: no protocol: /com/google/errorprone/error_prone_parent/1.0.8/error_prone_parent-1.0.8.pom
[ivy:resolve]   liferay-private: unable to get resource for com/google/errorprone#error_prone_ant;1.0.8: res=/com/google/errorprone/error_prone_ant/1.0.8/error_prone_ant-1.0.8.pom: java.net.MalformedURLException: no protocol: /com/google/errorprone/error_prone_ant/1.0.8/error_prone_ant-1.0.8.pom
[ivy:resolve]       :: jalopy#jalopy;1.5rc3: several problems occurred while resolving dependency: jalopy#jalopy;1.5rc3 {default=[default]}:
[ivy:resolve]   liferay-private: unable to get resource for jalopy#jalopy;1.5rc3: res=/jalopy/jalopy/1.5rc3/jalopy-1.5rc3-sources.jar: java.net.MalformedURLException: no protocol: /jalopy/jalopy/1.5rc3/jalopy-1.5rc3-sources.jar
[ivy:resolve]   liferay-private: unable to get resource for jalopy#jalopy;1.5rc3: res=/jalopy/jalopy/1.5rc3/jalopy-1.5rc3.pom: java.net.MalformedURLException: no protocol: /jalopy/jalopy/1.5rc3/jalopy-1.5rc3.pom
[ivy:resolve]       :: javax.servlet#javax.servlet-api;3.0.1: several problems occurred while resolving dependency: javax.servlet#javax.servlet-api;3.0.1 {default=[default]}:
[ivy:resolve]   several problems occurred while resolving dependency: net.java#jvnet-parent;1 {}:
[ivy:resolve]   liferay-private: unable to get resource for net/java#jvnet-parent;1: res=/net/java/jvnet-parent/1/jvnet-parent-1.jar: java.net.MalformedURLException: no protocol: /net/java/jvnet-parent/1/jvnet-parent-1.jar
[ivy:resolve]   liferay-private: unable to get resource for net/java#jvnet-parent;1: res=/net/java/jvnet-parent/1/jvnet-parent-1.pom: java.net.MalformedURLException: no protocol: /net/java/jvnet-parent/1/jvnet-parent-1.pom
[ivy:resolve]   liferay-private: unable to get resource for javax/servlet#javax.servlet-api;3.0.1: res=/javax/servlet/javax.servlet-api/3.0.1/javax.servlet-api-3.0.1.pom: java.net.MalformedURLException: no protocol: /javax/servlet/javax.servlet-api/3.0.1/javax.servlet-api-3.0.1.pom
[ivy:resolve]       :: javax.servlet.jsp#jsp-api;2.1: several problems occurred while resolving dependency: javax.servlet.jsp#jsp-api;2.1 {default=[default]}:
[ivy:resolve]   liferay-private: unable to get resource for javax/servlet/jsp#jsp-api;2.1: res=/javax/servlet/jsp/jsp-api/2.1/jsp-api-2.1-javadoc.jar: java.net.MalformedURLException: no protocol: /javax/servlet/jsp/jsp-api/2.1/jsp-api-2.1-javadoc.jar
[ivy:resolve]   liferay-private: unable to get resource for javax/servlet/jsp#jsp-api;2.1: res=/javax/servlet/jsp/jsp-api/2.1/jsp-api-2.1.pom: java.net.MalformedURLException: no protocol: /javax/servlet/jsp/jsp-api/2.1/jsp-api-2.1.pom
[ivy:resolve]       :: javax.mail#mail;1.4: several problems occurred while resolving dependency: javax.mail#mail;1.4 {default=[default]}:
[ivy:resolve]   liferay-private: unable to get resource for javax/mail#mail;1.4: res=/javax/mail/mail/1.4/mail-1.4-javadoc.jar: java.net.MalformedURLException: no protocol: /javax/mail/mail/1.4/mail-1.4-javadoc.jar
[ivy:resolve]   liferay-private: unable to get resource for javax/mail#mail;1.4: res=/javax/mail/mail/1.4/mail-1.4.pom: java.net.MalformedURLException: no protocol: /javax/mail/mail/1.4/mail-1.4.pom
[ivy:resolve]       :: com.liferay#net.sf.jargs;1.0: several problems occurred while resolving dependency: com.liferay#net.sf.jargs;1.0 {default=[default]}:
[ivy:resolve]   liferay-private: unable to get resource for com/liferay#net.sf.jargs;1.0: res=/com/liferay/net.sf.jargs/1.0/net.sf.jargs-1.0-sources.jar: java.net.MalformedURLException: no protocol: /com/liferay/net.sf.jargs/1.0/net.sf.jargs-1.0-sources.jar
[ivy:resolve]   liferay-private: unable to get resource for com/liferay#net.sf.jargs;1.0: res=/com/liferay/net.sf.jargs/1.0/net.sf.jargs-1.0.pom: java.net.MalformedURLException: no protocol: /com/liferay/net.sf.jargs/1.0/net.sf.jargs-1.0.pom
[ivy:resolve]       :: com.thoughtworks.qdox#qdox;1.12.1: several problems occurred while resolving dependency: com.thoughtworks.qdox#qdox;1.12.1 {default=[default]}:
[ivy:resolve]   several problems occurred while resolving dependency: org.codehaus#codehaus-parent;4 {}:
[ivy:resolve]   liferay-private: unable to get resource for org/codehaus#codehaus-parent;4: res=/org/codehaus/codehaus-parent/4/codehaus-parent-4.jar: java.net.MalformedURLException: no protocol: /org/codehaus/codehaus-parent/4/codehaus-parent-4.jar
[ivy:resolve]   liferay-private: unable to get resource for org/codehaus#codehaus-parent;4: res=/org/codehaus/codehaus-parent/4/codehaus-parent-4.pom: java.net.MalformedURLException: no protocol: /org/codehaus/codehaus-parent/4/codehaus-parent-4.pom
[ivy:resolve]   liferay-private: unable to get resource for com/thoughtworks/qdox#qdox;1.12.1: res=/com/thoughtworks/qdox/qdox/1.12.1/qdox-1.12.1.pom: java.net.MalformedURLException: no protocol: /com/thoughtworks/qdox/qdox/1.12.1/qdox-1.12.1.pom
[ivy:resolve]       :: xalan#serializer;2.7.1: several problems occurred while resolving dependency: xalan#serializer;2.7.1 {default=[default]}:
[ivy:resolve]   several problems occurred while resolving dependency: org.apache#apache;4 {}:
[ivy:resolve]   liferay-private: unable to get resource for org/apache#apache;4: res=/org/apache/apache/4/apache-4.jar: java.net.MalformedURLException: no protocol: /org/apache/apache/4/apache-4.jar
[ivy:resolve]   liferay-private: unable to get resource for org/apache#apache;4: res=/org/apache/apache/4/apache-4.pom: java.net.MalformedURLException: no protocol: /org/apache/apache/4/apache-4.pom
[ivy:resolve]   liferay-private: unable to get resource for xalan#serializer;2.7.1: res=/xalan/serializer/2.7.1/serializer-2.7.1.pom: java.net.MalformedURLException: no protocol: /xalan/serializer/2.7.1/serializer-2.7.1.pom
[ivy:resolve]       :: xalan#xalan;2.7.1: several problems occurred while resolving dependency: xalan#xalan;2.7.1 {default=[default]}:
[ivy:resolve]   several problems occurred while resolving dependency: org.apache#apache;4 {}:
[ivy:resolve]   liferay-private: unable to get resource for org/apache#apache;4: res=/org/apache/apache/4/apache-4.jar: java.net.MalformedURLException: no protocol: /org/apache/apache/4/apache-4.jar
[ivy:resolve]   liferay-private: unable to get resource for org/apache#apache;4: res=/org/apache/apache/4/apache-4.pom: java.net.MalformedURLException: no protocol: /org/apache/apache/4/apache-4.pom
[ivy:resolve]   liferay-private: unable to get resource for xalan#xalan;2.7.1: res=/xalan/xalan/2.7.1/xalan-2.7.1.pom: java.net.MalformedURLException: no protocol: /xalan/xalan/2.7.1/xalan-2.7.1.pom
[ivy:resolve]       ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[ivy:resolve] 
[ivy:resolve] 
[ivy:resolve] :: USE VERBOSE OR DEBUG MESSAGE LEVEL FOR MORE DETAILS

BUILD FAILED
E:\WORK\LIFERAY\TRAININGS\com.liferay.portal.plugins.sdk-7.0\portlets\build.xml:5: The following error occurred while executing this line:
E:\WORK\LIFERAY\TRAININGS\com.liferay.portal.plugins.sdk-7.0\build-common-plugins.xml:5: The following error occurred while executing this line:
E:\WORK\LIFERAY\TRAININGS\com.liferay.portal.plugins.sdk-7.0\build-common.xml:57: The following error occurred while executing this line:
E:\WORK\LIFERAY\TRAININGS\com.liferay.portal.plugins.sdk-7.0\build-common-ivy.xml:570: The following error occurred while executing this line:
E:\WORK\LIFERAY\TRAININGS\com.liferay.portal.plugins.sdk-7.0\build-common-ivy.xml:173: The following error occurred while executing this line:
E:\WORK\LIFERAY\TRAININGS\com.liferay.portal.plugins.sdk-7.0\build-common-ivy.xml:202: impossible to resolve dependencies:
    resolve failed - see output for details

Total time: 1 minute 58 seconds
```

Comment: Liferay 7 + JSF compatibility was only [announced on 2 Sep](https://web.liferay.com/de/web/neil.griffin/blog/-/blogs/announcement-support-for-jsf-in-liferay-portal-7-0-dxp), two weeks ago - wondering what worked before... Please check with the linked announcement and consider moving away from the deprecated plugins-sdk, rather use workspace - more people will be able help with those problems.

Comment: Also, please consider editing the question by replacing the screenshot with actual text (use the `preformatted` option). This way others might find this question when they stumble upon the same message and search for it. The text displayed on the screenshot can't be found on google

Comment: @OlafKock yes I remember now that I worked before with mvc not jsf, I thought no problem here since we both use on them the sdk. I fixed in the question what you noted

Comment: Check out [this Liferay Forum post](https://web.liferay.com/community/forums/-/message_boards/message/79147107). I think they are trying to do something similar to what you want to do.